# Changing the color of the 'active'

Tags: html, css

The active color is still White even after rgb is changed.

```css
.nav li>a:hover,
.nav .open>a:hover,
.nav li>a:focus,
.nav .open>a:focus,
.nav li>a:active,
.nav .open>a:active {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0)
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-m2p sidebar" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Foobar<b>Company</b></a>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I can not see any `li` in html code

Comment: Think you need to learn about basic css selectors - do a tutorial, it will save you a lot of time and questions.  But the main problems I see is you have nothing with a class of nav and no li so obviously your css is not styling anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead use of `nav` use `navbar` and inside `navbar a`

```css
.navbar a:hover,
.navbar .open>a:hover,
.navbar span>a:focus,
.navbar .open>a:focus,
.navbar a:active,
.navbar a:active {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0)
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-m2p sidebar" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Foobar<b>Company</b></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I would also like to make a hover to the other sub-menus

Answer (score 0):

**Use `.navbar` instead `.nav`** and I can not see any `li` element so remove it from css:

I recommand you learn about selector in css:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

```css
.navbar a:hover,
.navbar a:focus,
.navbar a:active {
     background-color:rgb(255,0,0);
     }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-m2p sidebar" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                Foobar<b>Company</b>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: what are you repeating the selector with `open` ?

Comment: you right... if he want apply style to `a` anyway it never mind if it open or not I will edit answer